# what is the id of a person in a person or group field made up of

Tags: 2010

what is the id of a person in a person or group field made up of. Using caml builder i noticed that my name has an id of 1.  I wouldnt have thought i have that ID in the entire sharepoint farm so im a bit confused.  Is it relative to the site collection / site. Does it link back to a hidden list like term columns do?

e.g

```
1;#My Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is the number that is assigned to a person when SharePoint adds them to the User Information List (http://somesite.com/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx) for that Site Collection.

Here's a great article describing it further (http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list).